# Putting String array in parameter, then comparing the elements to literal strings error?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an array

```
string test = {"test1, "test2"}
```

I have my function

```
void testing(string test){
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if(test[i] == "test1"){
      cout << "success" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I compile this, I get an error...why is that?
Is there a different approach?

Comment: `string test` doesn't look like an array. It looks like  `string`.

Comment: You are missing `"` for `test1` in `string test`.

Answer (score 2):

Your test variable should be declared as an array type

```
string test[] = {"test1", "test2"};
```

You also need to change the function signature from

```
void testing(string test)
```

to

```
void testing(string* test){
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote is not going to compile because of wrong declaration of string array.
replace

```
string test = {"test1, "test2"};
```

with

```
string test[]={"test1, "test2"};
```

## The following code uses the array in place without function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string test[]={"test1, "test2"};
for(auto& item:test)
{
    cout<<item<<endl;
}
```

## I think the best way to get this working with function is to use vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void testing(const vector<string>& strings)
{
    for (auto& item : strings)
    {
        cout << item << endl;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<string> strings = { "str1", "str2", "str3" };
    testing(strings);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```